# Allowed Parents/Children missing in AEM Components

Tags: aem

I am going through some of the online tutorials to learn AEM. According to the tutorial, when the component is created, some values need to be entered in Allowed Parents or Allowed Children. But, I do not see such an option in my window. When I try to create the component, I get the first window to enter the component title and other details. And then this window (please see the attached image), where NEXT button is disabled.

I am using AEM 6.2

Can you please let me know how to bring the NEXT button enabled, to get the Allowed parents window?

**Image**:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps something changed between the version the tutorial was written for and the version you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

It's applicable for templates only.

see https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2323149